# In strict mode, what is considered to be "gaining access to the global object"?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

http://jsbin.com/ifabem/2/edit

```
"use strict";

window.x = "Hello World";
alert(x); // this does't throw an exception in strict mode
```

Why doesn't accessing x directly in the last statement violate strict mode and throw an exception?

Is it the case that a violating is only writing a new value into the global object, but reading and even modifying an existing object allowed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phrase "gaining access to the global object" does not occur in the spec, so doesn't have a clear definition; but looking through Appendix C of the spec (a non-normative listing of the effects of strict-mode), the only restriction that I think could be described that way is this one:

> Assignment to an undeclared identifier or otherwise unresolvable reference does not create a property in the global object. When a simple assignment occurs within strict mode code, its *LeftHandSide* must not evaluate to an unresolvable Reference. If it does a **ReferenceError** exception is thrown (8.7.2).

So you're not allowed to *add* a property to the global object without using `var` or `window.` or whatnot, but there's nothing to stop you from *getting* a property of the global object — or even setting the value of an existing property.

(By the way, the relevant bit of §8.7.2 is not terribly meaningful out-of-context, but for completeness' sake, it's this:

> 3. If IsUnresolvableReference(*V*), then
>       a. If IsStrictReference(*V*) is **true**, then
>           i. Throw **ReferenceError** exception.
>       b. Call the [[Put]] internal method of the global object, passing 
>           GetReferencedName(*V*) for the property name, *W* for the value, 
>           and **false** for the *Throw* flag.

)

Answer (score 1):

I think by '*gaining access to the global object*' is meant gaining access to it *from within a non global object/scope*. So this will throw a reference error:

```
function foo(){
 "use strict";
 bar = '3';
}
foo(); //=> ReferenceError: bar is not defined
```

In other words I would say, 'strict mode' enforces the assignment of variables within their own scope. That's why window.x is perfectly possible.

On the other hand, one *can* address `window` from within a function:

```
function foo(){
 "use strict";
 window.bar = '3';
}
foo();      //=> no error
alert(bar); //=> 3
```

So, in essence, `use strict` prevents declaring variables without the keyword `var` *or*  without a reference to their own namespace within a non global scope.

Comment: This does not throw: http://jsbin.com/ufokid/edit#javascript,html See @ruakh's answer.

Comment: Yes, and does that prove something?

Comment: I mean, it's a perfectly valid closure, so, in what way does that contradict anything?

Comment: Let's just say I preferred @ruakh's answer and leave it at that.

Answer (score 0):

undeclared globals (variables instantiated without var in functions) are one instance,

another is that the methods **call** and **apply** no longer convert a primitive to a global  object-(where a string becomes String, and null or undefined pass  window) as the 'this' value.